# How to make a macro in Google Sheets that runs when a cell changes value and then formats a range based on the value in the cell

Tags: google-sheets, google-apps-script, conditional-formatting

I have some formulas that pulls out data for different graphs in Google Sheets.
These data can either be in full numbers (e.g. Revenue) or in %.
I have a dropdown for each graph where the user can input whether the data is full numbers or %, which works fine and the graph also shows the correct data.

But I would like a macro that runs whenevever the cell with the dropdown (full numbers or %) changes, and then formats the range where the numbers are to the correct format - either full numbers with 1000 separator and no decimals (1,000) or as percentage with 1 decimal (1,5%).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Conditional number format (whole number, percentage) based on the value in another cell](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/91997/conditional-number-format-whole-number-percentage-based-on-the-value-in-anoth)

Comment: Using a macro might be an overkilling solution. Have you tried to use the built-in conditional formatting feature (see the linked Q/A from the previous comment). If still want to use a macro, you should use Google Apps Script triggers, edit or change triggers. If you need help with Google Apps Script, please show what you tried and a brief description of your search efforts as is suggested in [ask].

Comment: Thanks both, it seems to be working